# how to rotate bitmap in android on center point using matrix

Tags: android, bitmap, matrix, android-imageview

I use matrix to rotate my image, it's working but i have some problem with new image bitmap.
The new bitmap have some space even though I have set the pivot. What should i do to rotate the image but i don't want the space. I use this code below to rotate the bitmap:

Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sticker01);
int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(rotate, width/2, height/2);

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                          width, height, matrix, true);
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

imageView --> width & height = WRAP_CONTENT

Rotate 0 degree:
[image]

Rotate 10 degree:
[image]
It has space around the real image..

Rotate 50 degree:
[image]
It has space around the real image (even bigger space)..

Comment: hi dear you get your ans or not

Answer (score 0):

Change the imageview scaleType:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use matrix post rotate with mid value

matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);